# Windows 10 cmd closes immediately, The screen cannot be set to the number of lines and columns specified

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to open a CMD to do stuff but it keeps closing immediately. 
The reason I need it is to get a Facebook hash for my Android project. 
To get around cmd I tried a GUI app to get the hash and it returned with the cmd result

> The screen cannot be set to the number of lines and columns specified.

I don't know what could have set my cmd size, I rarely use it.

Is there a way to change or reset the line and column sizes in cmd **without** opening the cmd itself?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, try running PowerShell.  In PowerShell, run:
CMD

To fix the issue, you could try editing the registry.
[StackOverflow: Where in windows registry the console width is stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664039/where-in-windows-registry-the-console-width-is-stored)

Comment: I tried it thanks. 
The app I wanted to run opens a cmd and not a powershell unfortunately :/ but since then I reinstalled windows and all is fine